# QT Creator's code completion for function overloading is buggy

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am using QT Creator on Ubuntu 14.04, to make a C++ project using cmake (not using qmake). In my source code editor, if I type a function name that is recognised, then next to the function name a code completion box will appear. This box consists of a down arrow, and next it the function prototype.

Now, it seems obvious that pressing this arrow should then reveal the other function prototypes, in the case when the function is overloaded and several prototypes exist. However, if I click this down arrow, the box just disappears completely. It does not reveal the other prototypes, and the first prototype and down arrow disappear too. This happens on all functions I have come across, both from external libraries, and those defined myself in my code.

Does anybody else have this issue? Any ideas on how to solve it? Thanks!

Alternatively, if you are using QT Creator on Ubuntu and you **don't** have this issue, could you let me know which version of QT Creator and Ubuntu you have? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to press up/down arrows after dialog appears.